# How to do geo fencing in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to do geo fencing in iphone?

Is there any API available?

If any sample code available please share with me.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497).
It contains all the info you need.

Comment: TQ mortenfast, but how can i get the places around me?

Comment: See the [Getting the User’s Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9) chapter in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To resume :
- Add the good tag in your info plist (location, location-services, gps...)
- Use the `startMonitoringForRegion` on the `CLLocationManager`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-started-geofencing-ios or you could get this book which also covers it in detail http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geolocation-iOS-Mobile-Positioning-Mapping/dp/1449308449

Answer (score 0):

Following examples should you give more idea on geofencing:

- http://www.creativebloq.com/ipad/get-started-geofencing-ios-9122867
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/geofencing-with-core-location/